# How to change mesh/model of an armature?

Tags: modeling, animation, mesh, rigging, pose-mode

I already have an rigged character in which there is already an animation associated in it, I want to change the mesh and to use another model on the armature. I am a beginner at don't know much about blender rigging, I am not getting any solution which would work for me.

Comment: You need to parent the new character object to the armature, make sure that the default character pose is aligned with the default armature pose

Comment: As moonboots said, Change armature to "rest" position. Then parent model to armature, and do weight painting to each bone.